# How to get all grandchildren in one to many relationship HQL?

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, one-to-many, cascade

I currently have a MySQL table called `Section`, and each entry in `Section` has a bunch of rows in the `News` table.  In each `News` entry, I have a bunch of rows in `Comments` table.

It's a `many to one` relationship between `News` and `Section`, and similarly `many to one` between `Comments` and `News`.  This is a unidirectional relationship from the children.

This is probably very easy, but I'm new to HQL, how would I query for all the `Comments` for a particular `Section`?  Is it a bunch of joins of recursive selects?

I apologize I don't know what this is called.  Is it cascading?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of `cascading` is about updating/inserting/removing a group of related entities , querying has nothing to do with the `cascading` in JPA /Hibernate

In your case , you can use `fetch join` to issue a single JOIN SQL to get all the children for a given parent .

The difference between `fetch join` and `normal join` is that `fetch join` will also cause all children objects to be initialized along with their parent in a single select such that you can avoid the potential N+1 problem when you loop through the children of the parent.

You can issue the `fetch join` using something like the following syntax:

```
from Section as section
left join fetch section.news as new
left join fetch new.comments
```

Comment: actually my table is structured in a way that parents don't have access to the children (as in the relationship is unidirectional from the children).  It's a `many to one` relationship, where `Comments` has a field that's pointing to the `id` of `News`, and `News` to `Section`.  In this case I can't use something like `section.news` (since `news` is not a column).

Comment: Maybe I should add the `one to many` relationship to the parent tables, so it forms a bidirectional relationship?  I'm just afraid that it'll decrease performance when I query the parent and I don't actually need the children.